# Find all the combinations for n sets of k elements

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, combinations

I have an array of structs

```
typedef struct st1
{
  double start;
  double step;
  double stop;
} ST;
```

I need to find all the posible combinations of those Optimization parameters going from start to stop in step steps.

For instance:

```
array[0].start = 0
array[0].step = 1
array[0].stop = 2

array[1].start = 5
array[1].step = 1
array[1].stop = 6
```

The combinations would be:

0,5 0,6 1,5 1,6 2,5 2,6

¿How can I implement this for a N size array of options in C?

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  ....
}
```

Comment: Well... I've solved similar problems with nested loops when having a fixed array size. The problem is that the array size is variable. I'm not looking for an implementation but a clue on how to implement it. Thanks for your comment anyway. I wish I were still doing homework, but that was longtime ago ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: @JimMischel: Probably a duplicate, but not of that post. This one appears to be about permutations not combinations, OP's title and confusing use of terminology not withstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pseudo code (actually [Kalkulon](http://www.kalkulon.de) code) which can be simply translated to C code:

```
::array={{0,1,2},{5,1,6}},
::N=Size(array),
::combination={0,0},

comb()=
(
 n=0,
 do(
  finishCtr = 0,
  i = n,
  for(j = 0; j < N; j++; // do
   maxsteps=(array[j,2] - array[j,0]) / array[j,1] + 1,
   steps = i % maxsteps, // modulo
   i = ip(i / maxsteps), // integer division
   elem = array[j,0] + steps * array[j,1],
   if(i > 0 && steps == 0; finishCtr++),  
   combination[j] = elem
  ),
  // print result if not already all combinations are done 
  if(finishCtr < N; PrintLn((string)combination)),
  n++
 ; // do-while 
 finishCtr < N
 )
);
```

output:

```
{0, 5}
{1, 5}
{2, 5}
{0, 6}
{1, 6}
{2, 6}
```